# Why is the alert not displayed?

Tags: javascript

Following a tutorial about game development with HTML5. And I can't figure out why this piece of code won't display the alert when I push the `up` key on my keyboard.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var keys = [];

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  delete keys[e.keyCode]
}, false);

if (keys[38]) alert("yep");
```

The Chrome console clearly shows that `keys[38]` is `true` and typing `if (keys[38]) alert("yep");` in the console displays the alert. I think I am missing a fundamental thing here (or being fundamentally stupid). I will be glad to provide more info in case there is no obvious mistake in the JS code.

Thanks!

Comment: What/When do you think `if (keys[38]) alert("yep");` is doing? That if runs before you type any keys.

Comment: More importantly, **when** do you think it is doing it.

Comment: When javascript engine parses that line, the `keys[38]` is still not defined. And 2011 MacBook Pro it's not relevant here.

Comment: You're **adding event listeners**. Only when the event listeners trigger (meaning a key is pressed) will the `function(e){...}` code run. And your `if (keys...` code is **outside** the event listener trigger function.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I said with other words the same that you are answering.

Comment: Read better before comments like that...

Comment: You should puth the alert inside the event listener in order for it to kick in... check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` will be called right at the end of your tick. The listeners start firing once you've left that tick. Hence, there's no chance for the `keys` array to be set when the `if` is executed.

The only pieces of your code that will be called afterwards are two callbacks passed to `keydown` and `keyup` events. If you want to react to those events, your code should reside *inside* of those callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your code (the `alert`) **inside** the event listener like so:

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 38) {
    alert('BOOYAKA');
  }
}, false);
```